# Why this update query only update one record once

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$coll->update(
  array(
    "uid"=(int)$uid,
    "status"=>1,
    "time"=>array('$gt'=>0,'$lte'=>$time)
  ),
  array(
    '$set'=>array("status"=>0)
  )
);
```

If you can't read PHP, CLI version of above code:

```
db.we.update({"uid":1,"status":1,"time":{"$lte":1324403899}},{"$set":{status:0}})
```

where `time` is a timestamp integer, and status is int 0 or 1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the MongoDB default behaviour for updates. If you want to update multiple documents at once, you'll explicitly have to provide the *multi* flag:

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )
```

so you'd have to use

```
db.we.update({"uid":1, "status":1, "time" : {"$lte":1324403899}},
             {"$set":{status:0}}, 
             false, 
             true);
```

instead.

From the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating):

> If you are coming from SQL, be aware that by default, update() only modifies the first matched object. If you want to modify all matched objects, you need to use the multi flag.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear answer. up-voted. And for those who might face the same question in PHP, the way to add options is to append array("multiple"=>ture) in the update function.

Answer (score 1):

Now MongoDB is using updateMany to update multiple documents: 
db.collection.updateMany(, , )

```
    db.collection.updateMany(criteria, objNew)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this was done in PHP initially, this may be of use to anyone using PHP:

```
$collection->update(

    array("uid"=>(int)$uid,"status"=>1,"time"=>array('$gt'=>0,'$lte'=>$time)), //search criteria

    array('$set'=>array('status'=>0)), //update criteria

    array('multiple'=>true) //options

);
```